# When using ScreenManager to load image as a button I get Invalid property name

Tags: python, image, kivy

When I use default code for screenmanager to switch between the screens it works:

```
<MainWindow>:
    name:'Main'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'horizontal'
        size: root.width, root.height


        Button:
            text:'Hello'
            font_size:32
            color:1,1,1,1
            
            on_press: 
                app.root.current='second'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
```

***BUT when I change source so that the button is an image, loaded from the same folder and run it, I get this:

```
<MainWindow>:
    name:'Main'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'horizontal'
        size: root.width, root.height


        Button:
            #text:'Hello'
            #font_size:32
            #color:1,1,1,1
            Image:
                source:'photo.png'
                        
            on_press: 
                app.root.current='second'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
```

```
 >>   29:               app.root.current='second'
      30:               root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
      31:
 ...
 Invalid property name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an `Image` as a `Button`, you can extend the `Image` class with `ButtonBehavior`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.button.html#example).

Or, you can use the properties of the `Button`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button.background_normal), like this:

```
    Button:
        #text:'Hello'
        #font_size:32
        #color:1,1,1,1
        background_normal: 'photo.png'
        # Image:
        #     source:'photo.png'
                    
        on_press: 
            app.root.current='second'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
```